# Java opencv unblur part of image around the mouse cursor

Tags: java, opencv, gaussianblur

I have an image on which gaussian blur is applied through this code

```
try {           
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        Mat im = Imgcodecs.imread("bin\\" + backImage[randNum]);    
        Mat dst = new Mat();                
        Imgproc.GaussianBlur(im, dst, new Size(55, 55) ,8 , 8);
        Imgcodecs.imwrite("bin\\gauLock.jpg", dst);               
      } catch (Exception e) {
         dispose();          
      }
```

Now I want to unblur the area around the mouse cursor

Somewhat like [this](https://www.canva.com/?referrer=photo-blur-landing-page&utm_source=onboarding)

So my questions are

- Is this possible?
- Can this be done using only opencv?
- If yes then how?

Comment: Information is lost when blurring. Hence, no, you cannot "unblur". If you want to achieve the same effect, you must have the original image + the blurred image and take pixel from one of both images depending on the position of the cursor.

Comment: Can u explain this cause I have access to both the images